# height of the body to fit 100% of what ever resolution the monitor is

Tags: html, css

is i t possible to get the body or any other element to fill the whole height of the browser in any resolution with css?

many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try using:

```
html,body{
height:100%;
}
```

This is often used to force scroll bars in browsers that only show scroll bars once the content on the page forces the height to be below the fold. (keeping the page consistent and stopping it from jumping left and right depending on page height).